# Template Class Array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I am trying to do a project for an algorithms class that requires implementing different sorting algorithms. I am trying to declare an array using the template class as shown. I have to keep the function definitions the same and therefore cannot change any of the parameters.  My question is for my array declaration, I get the error "Non type template argument is a non constant expression." What is the correct way to declare a template array? Any help will be appreciated.

```
#ifndef __SORTING_HPP
#define __SORTING_HPP

#include "SortingHelper.h"
#include <iostream>
template <class T> 
class Sorting
{    
    public:
        T selectionsort(T* data, int size);
        T insertionsort(T* data, int size);
        T mergesort(T* data, int size, T* temp);
        T quicksort(T* data, int size);
        T data;
};
template <class T>  void selectionsort(T* data, int size)
{
    std::array<T*, size> myarray = data;
    int min = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    if (isSorted(data, size))
    {
        return *data;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (int j=i+1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (data[j] < data[min])
                min= j;
           }
           if (min != i)
           {
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[min];
                data[min] = temp;
           }
        }
   }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Change
template <class T>  void selectionsort(T* data, int size) to 
template <class T>  void Sorting::selectionsort(T* data, int size)

Comment: Hmmm...but now I get "Sorting is not a class, namespace, or enumeration"

Comment: That `std::array<T*, size>` looks strange to me.  Don't you mean `std::array<T, size>`?  Do you really want an array of pointers?

Comment: @IronCode: That's doubtful. Please have a look at the latest edit of my answer. A collection of `T` and a collection of `T*` are two quite different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> template <class T>  void selectionsort(T* data, int size)
> {
>     std::array<T*, size> myarray = data;
> ```

`size` is only known at run time. The size of an `std::array` has to be known at compile time.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Use `std::vector<T*>` instead of `std::array<T*, size>`.
2. Make `size` a template argument: `template <class T, int size> void selectionsort(T* data)`.

What's better depends on what you actually want to do.

---

Mind that I'm not sure that your code really does what you intend it to do. You seem to be using `T*` in your functions' parameters as a way to say "pointer to a number of `T`s", while in your `selectionsort` function you are suddenly dealing with a collection of `T` pointers.

In other words, `std::array<T*, size>` (or `std::vector<T*>`) is a **collection of `T*`, not a collection of `T`**. You will probably want to use `std::array<T, size>` (or `std::vector<T>`) and then use the `T*` that you receive in the function to copy the `T` objects that the `T*` points to into the container. For example:

```
std::vector<T> myarray(data, data + size);
```

Comment: Ahh okay I see now. Sorry I struggle with the concept of pointers. But just really quick when I use a vector, I receive the error no member name 'vector' in namespace std?

Comment: @IronCode: You have to `#include` the correct standard-library headers. In the case of `std::vector`, `#include <vector>`.